# DynamoDB - How to get all items with any partition key, but with a range of sort key values?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I've got a DynamoDB table with a bunch of pokemon in it, heehee, and I'm trying to get them out ordered by level.

I've got a GSI with pokemon (the name, pikachu, etc) as the partition key, and level (number value) as the sort key.

I want to query everyone over a certain level. Here's my code:

```
db.query({
  TableName: "pokemon",
  IndexName: "level",
  KeyConditionExpression: `lv > :zero`,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":zero": 0
  }
}, function (error, reply) {
  return console.log(error || reply)
})
```

And I get this error

`ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: pokemon`

I've also tried this

```
db.query({
  TableName: "pokemon",
  IndexName: "level",
  KeyConditionExpression: `pokemon = not_null and lv > :zero`,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":name": 'not_null',
    ":zero": 0
  }
}, function (error, reply) {
  return console.log(error || reply)
})
```

And get this error:

`ValidationException: Invalid condition in KeyConditionExpression: Multiple attribute names used in one condition`

I can't seem to take any value for the partition key. It keeps yelling at me : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `KeyConditionExpression` parameter to provide a specific value for the partition key.

Your query should look like this (in pseudocode):

```
{
  "TableName": "pokem",
  "IndexName": "level",
  "KeyConditionExpression": "#name = :name And #level > :level",
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":name": "name",
    ":level": "level"
  },
  "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    "#name": "pikachu",
    "#level": "0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it. So, I can't get a list sorted by level the way my data is currently in there, without doing a scan anyway.

Comment: Im not sure I follow.  The query results will come back sorted by the sort key, so they will be in order.

Comment: It's okay. Just a test db, so not important. Still learning. The partition key is type (psychic, etc), and the sort key is the pokemon name (pikachu, etc), so I can only have one of each pokemon in there. So when I pull them out of the GSI, they're not sorted by level. Unless I'm doing something wrong that I'm not noticing.